# Anemometer GUI in Python tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, canvas

I need to create GUI of anemometer in tkinter and i dont know how to start. I am not so good with circle.
It should looks like i attached in img.
Thanks for helping.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LM9X.jpg)

I tryed to do this by myself but is to hard for me now.